# How to call and import database in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I have a file name "database.sqlite" which contains data that I have to use.

I wonder how to import it into my Eclipse IDE and how to call the data in this file?

Please give me some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the link below and follow steps from 6 onwards, but instead of copying it to **sdcard** copy it to **data\data\your package name\database**

http://androidbyhp.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-how-to-insert-images-songs-or.html#comments

I hope this helps and this is what you are looking for.